# How to split a string after the first occurence of a character?

Tags: regex, string, split

Given strings

```
s1 = "4903485, abcfood, efbarghi"
```

and

```
s2 = "abcbar, defooghi"
```

How can I split s1 into "4903485" and "abcfood, efbarghi" and s2 into "" and "abcbar, defooghi".
The first part should contain the number (if there exists a number), the second part should contain the rest of the string after the "," (the rest of the string can contain other commas...but should not be splitted again)

I suppose this could be done with s.split(/regexp/), but what should this regexp be?

Comment: What is the language? Have you written anything to solve that yet?

Comment: Please show some research effort before asking a question and asking for code. Anyway here is a good [link](https://regexone.com/) to experiment and learn regexp

Comment: for regex go here: https://www.regex101.com/  but such simple check could be done easy in most languages without regex involved; what's your lang?

Comment: I need this regexp for data preparation in Dataiku... already tried this one: ([0-9]*), (.*) But if there is no number/comma in the first part of the string it will not work..

Comment: Try with `(?:([0-9]*), )?(.*)`

Comment: I like those typical spring questions: "I did not learn all year, but still have to do my assignment, please, do it for me!" and the answer is NO - you do learn and do it yourself!

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code snippet. The Regex `/^(\d+|)\,?/g` will give you first occurrence of delimiter comma (,). If there is nothing in first part then it will give you empty.

```js
function SplitTest(s, i){
  var regex = /^(\d+|)\,?/g;
  var splitData = s.split(regex);
  return splitData[i];
}

console.log(SplitTest("4903485, abcfood, efbarghi", 1));
console.log(SplitTest("4903485, abcfood, efbarghi", 2));

console.log(SplitTest(", abcfood, efbarghi", 1));
console.log(SplitTest(", abcfood, efbarghi", 2));
```